# a part string is missing when echo in bash

Tags: bash, echo

The bash script is:

```
echo Updating hostname and IP address ...
echo ${config_template_ip}
echo "ssh-keygen -R ${config_template_ip} -f /home/testusr/.ssh/known_hosts"
echo ${config_template_ip}
```

The output is

```
Updating hostname and IP address ...
10.100.224.250
 -f /home/testusr/.ssh/known_hosts
10.100.224.250
```

why didn't "ssh-keygen -R ${config_template_ip} " on STDOUT, and how to solve that?

Comment: `$config_template_ip` ends with a Carriage Return. If you read that from a file, you need to convert all the CRLF line breaks to LF. Use the tool `dos2unix` to fix the file.

Comment: If you don't want to convert the file, you can remove the CR from the variable. If you're using the `read` command to read it, you can have it trim the CR by adding that to `IFS`, like this: `IFS="$IFS"$'\r' read ...`. You can also remove it explicitly with `config_template_ip=${config_template_ip%$'\r'}`. In either case, note that the `$'\r'` syntax is bash-specific, and will not work in other shells. BTW, you can also do these in addition to converting the file, in case someone regenerates the file later and forgets to re-convert it.